# Why code inside Generic functions ignores overloaded == operator

Tags: c#

What is the workaround to this problem?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new Test();
        var b = new Test();
        var eq = Check(a, b);
    }

    private static bool Check<T>(T a, T b) where T : class
    {
        return a == b; //will not call overloaded == 
    }
}
public class Test
{
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Test other = obj as Test;
        if (ReferenceEquals(other, null)) return false;
        return true;
    }
    public static bool operator ==(Test left, Test right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Test left, Test right)
    {
        return !(left == right);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you replace the `==` operator with `ReferenceEquals`, does that work?

Comment: @code4life `==` is already performing a reference equality check; the correct solution is to use `Equals`.

Comment: == is an overload, not an override.  When you don't constrain a generic type, it acts as if it's an object for overload purposes.  That is, it takes the lowest common denominator of all possible type T.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `==` operator is not used because your generic method exists independently of the types you will use for `T`. It has no way of knowing that all types used as `T` will overload the `==` operator... You can use the `Equals` method instead:

```
private static bool Check<T>(T a, T b) where T : class
{
    return Equals(a, b);
}
```

Comment: First this is generics and the type is known at compile time second why it doesn't check it at runtime

Comment: @AlexBurtsev the generic type is not known at compile time.  C# generics do not work like C++ templates.  They are compiled so as to work with *any possible* type arguments, not *with type arguments that are actually used.*

Comment: @AlexBurtsev second, operators are not virtual; i.e., they are overloaded not overridden, which means there is no virtual (run-time) dispatch.

Comment: The type is known at compile time in the `Main` method, **not** in the `Check` method. And it doesn't check at runtime, because C# is a statically typed language; it doesn't do late binding like in dynamic languages (except when you use `dynamic`)

Answer (score 4):

The 'solution' here is to call

```
 private static bool Check<T>(T a, T b) where T : class
 {
     //return a == b;      // will not call overloaded == 
     return a.Equals(b);   // will cal overloaded Equals
 }
```

Comment: You also need to check that a is not null... It's easier to use the static Equals method

Comment: Yes, `a == b` is not same as `a.Equals(b)` as the former wont explode if `a` is null (or at least shouldn't). Better to use: `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(a, b)`

Answer (score 3):

It's a known behavior. MSDN says:

> When applying the `where T : class` constraint, it is recommended that
>   you do not use the == and != operators on the type parameter because
>   **these operators will test for reference identity only, not for value equality**. This is the case even if these operators are overloaded in
>   a type used as an argument.

To check equality you have to implement IEqualityComparer (or directly call one of the Equal methods).

Comment: +1 for mentioning `IEqualityComparer`, but I think you meant `IEquatable<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

The workaround is to call the virtual Equals method, and override that:

```
private static bool Check<T>(T a, T b) where T : class 
{ 
    return a.Equals(b);
}
```

The overloaded `==` operator is resolved at *compile time*, so it is resolved to the System.Object implementation of the operator.  A virtual method call is dispatched at *run time*, so the override of System.Object.Equals (if any) will get called.

In your code, the virtual Equals call is occurring in the overloaded `==` method, which is not called; that's why the Equals override is not called.

Another solution, if you have control of the classes being passed to the method, would be to constrain to `IEquatable<T>`, and implement that in your classes:

```
private static bool Check<T>(T a, T b) where T : class, IEquatable<T>
{ 
    return a.Equals(b);
}
```

That will cause the overload to resolve to the `Equals(T)` method, which will save some type checking at run time.

Comment: `a == b` is not same as `a.Equals(b)` as the former wont explode if `a` is null (or at least shouldn't). Better to use: `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(a, b)`

Comment: @nawfal That is true.  I should have included a null check in the example code, but `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals` no doubt does all the proper checks that I forgot, and so is a better way to invoke the `Equals` method.  Of course, if you call the equality comparer *and* do the null checks in the Equals override, you'll be doing them twice.